# How to Restrict multiple login at a time with same user name and password in diffrent browser in java script

Tags: javascript, openerp-7

If a user logged in one browser and at the same time another user may trying to login with same user name and password at that particular case the browser must stop the user to login. How to implement this function using Javascript can any one help me.

Comment: Do you have anything to show us?

Comment: You have to do this server side, javascript does not work between browsers. There are a lot of problems with this approach. Figuring out when a session expires is one of them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your attempt so far. This website is about helping people with specific problems. If you can show you've made some effort you're more likely to get help.

Comment: Hi, i am having one function which was able to restrict the user with wrong credentials. In the same way i am trying to add at the middle of the code as, If the user already logged in and some other user trying to log in with same credentials in different browser, the login has to restrict. The code was in answer formate. do_login: function (db, login, password) {

Comment: Thank you for the response brduca and odedra

Answer (score 0):

```
do_login: function (db, login, password) {
    var self = this;
    self.hide_error();

    self.$(".oe_login_pane").fadeOut("slow");

    return this.session.session_authenticate(db, login, password).then(function() {
        self.remember_last_used_database(db);

        if (self.has_local_storage && self.remember_credentials) {
            localStorage.setItem(db + '|last_login', login);
            //console.log('check login true');
            window.alert('check login true');
            console.log('session' + this.session);
        }
        self.trigger('login_successful');
    }, function () {
        self.$(".oe_login_pane").fadeIn("fast", function() {
            console.log('check login false');
            self.show_error(_t("Invalid username or password check"));
        });
    });
},
show_error: function(message) {
    this.$el.addClass("oe_login_invalid");
    this.$(".oe_login_error_message").text(message);
},
hide_error: function() {
    this.$el.removeClass('oe_login_invalid');
},
```

});
instance.web.client_actions.add("login", "instance.web.Login");